# wpf how to download data from xml file

Tags: wpf, linq-to-xml

how to download data from file xml

data file in the application

```
    XDocument dane = XDocument.Load("gpw.xml");
    List<pozycjeGpw> listaGpw = new List<pozycjeGpw>();

    private void listBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listaGpw = (from item in dane.Descendants("pozycja")
                    select new pozycjeGpw()
                    {
                        nazwa_notowania = (item.Element("nazwa_notowania").Value),
                        biezacy = (item.Element("biezacy").Value),
                        zmiana = (item.Element("zmiana").Value),
                        zmiana2 = (item.Element("zmiana2").Value),
                        otwarcie = (item.Element("otwarci").Value),
                        max = (item.Element("max").Value),
                        min = (item.Element("min").Value),
                    }).ToList();
        listaGpw.Insert(0, new pozycjeGpw() { nazwa_notowania = "", biezacy = "", zmiana = "", zmiana2 = "", otwarcie = "", max = "", min = "" });
    }
```

Comment: We need to know more about what you are asking. Can you show the XML content and expand on your question?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
String result = webClient.DownloadString(yourUrlOfTheXmlFile);
textBox.Text = result;
```

Doing this in a form with a TextBox called textBox should display the downloaded xml file on the screen.

If you want to load this XML from a file on your system, you can also use this:

```
String result = File.ReadAllText(pathOfYourXmlFile);
textBox.Text = result;
```

Comment: wants to download data from xml file and display them on the screen
xml file is downloaded locally in the application

Comment: I can see you have a list of objects with a name and properties that I cannot identify. You take info from the loaded XML, stick it into objects that you put in the list. But what is then the actual question?

Comment: Well I have managed to show XML data on a screen in WPF. It's not hard.

Comment: This is easy if you know how to do it

Comment: It's easy when you know what you actually want to do. The question above is not clear. Nobody knows what you're trying to do.

Comment: want to display data from an xml (data exchange) file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do but from your comments it appears that you have an xml file and you want to display it in a WPF application. To do this you can use `XMLDataProvider` and `HierarchicalDataTemplates` / `DataTemplates`. Here is a short tutorial on how to do it: http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.com/2011/11/wpf-working-with-xml-and.html